# How to derive a formula involves a delta function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, amplituhedron

I watched the [video: Geometry of scattering amplitudes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCi195e9QD4) of lectures by Nima Arkani-Hamed. At 3:00:00, he derived the following equation:
\begin{align}
& \int \frac{dc_1}{c_1} \cdots \frac{dc_5}{c_5}/_{GL(1)} \delta^{4|4} [c_1 Z_1 + \cdots c_5 Z_5] \\
& =\frac{1}{<1234><2345><3451><4512><5123>} \delta^4[ <1234>\eta_5 + \cdots ]
\end{align}
I think here $c_1, \ldots, c_5$ are real numbers and $Z_1, \ldots, Z_5$ are 4-dimensional vectors. Denote by $Z$ the 4 by 5 matrix with columns $Z_1, \ldots, Z_5$. The symbol $<1235>$ denotes the minor of $Z$ with 1,2,3,4 rows and 1,2,3,5 columns. Other symbols $<i,j,k,l>$ are defined similarly. But I don't know the symbol $\eta_i$.

Since I am not very familiar with physics notation,I could not understand some parts of the prove. How to prove this equation explicitly?

Comment: Questions on this site are supposed to be self-contained and not require watching the first three hours of an eleven-hour video. Unless you define all the notation, the question is unclear.

Comment: A delta function inside an integral like this typically enforces that certain conservation laws are met (for example, there's a delta function in the scattering amplitude calculations of "ordinary" QFT which enforces the condition that the total initial four-momentum is equal to the total final four-momentum. Configurations where this isn't true contribute zero to the integral.).